# How can I automatically full-screen a program in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, fullscreen

Usually, the first thing I do after I have started darktable is press F11 to have it in real full-screen mode.  I wonder whether I can have this automatically somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs in Lubuntu remember the size when they were closed.  Some do not.  Lubuntu users can open some or all programs maximized by editing ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml. A very detailed how to can be found at the Community Documentation site

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Launching_Windows_Maximized

Comment: OP wanted `fullscreen` rather than `maximized`. So I've written an answer for that. It is based on the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use darktable myself but there is a way to launch *amenable* programs full screen automatically without having to press `F11` after loading the program.

To do so, follow all the precautions mentioned in [Launching Windows Maximized](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Launching_Windows_Maximized) but use this code in the Applications section of `lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<fullscreen>yes</fullscreen>
```

After determining how you will specify your darktable window with `xprop`, your "rule" would be something like this (putting what is specific to darktable in place of "geany"):

```
<application name="geany" type="normal">
  <fullscreen>yes</fullscreen>
</application>
```

As usual, you'll need to run `openbox --reconfigure` in a terminal after saving `lubuntu-rc.xml` to let the window manager know you've changed something. Or you may have set up your Openbox right-click menu to have the "reconfigure" option available there.